# How can I tell TYPO3, to not convert SVG graphics to GIF graphics

Tags: svg, typo3, typo3-6.1.x

I'm using TYPO3 6.1 with an Amazon S3 bucket over the File Abstraction Layer.
Now I want to add an SVG image with the "Images Only" content element.
I can select it, but in the frontend, it shows not the svg. It creates a gif file and shows that.

Expected output:

```
<img src="https://[MYBUCKET].s3.amazonaws.com/images/partner/samsung.svg">
```

Actual output:

```
<img src="https://[MYBUCKET].s3.amazonaws.com/_temp_/csm_samsung_caab942deb.gif">
```

I don't want that TYPO3 convert or copy any File. It should always use the original path. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Look in "Admin Tools" -> "Install" and select "Image Processing" there u can changes the processing file type/format.
But I will not recomment it but about SVG read [This](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Svg/Index.html)

Comment: disable Image Processing seems also to disable thumbnails in the file browser. Thats not good.

The documentation about typoscript you linked doesn't help me.
1. I don't want to insert the svg with typoscript, BE Users should do this with content elements
2. I do not want dirty flash fallbacks. The Website is only for HTML5 browser.

Answer (score 0):

Don't disable image processing. Make sure that SVG is defined as an image type in the [GFX][imagefile_ext] setting in the Install Tool. If SVG isn't explicitly defined as being an image type, TYPO3 will convert it.